# How can I print the closest Point?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, matrix, point

I have my program with the closest pair of point in a array of n (number inserted by the user) points, I created the algorithm for it and it works giving back the minor delta (distance between points), I used the divide et impera approach.
I tried to put them in a list when they go inside the BruteForce() method, like inside the brute force I start a method that do this:

```
public double bruteForce(Point[] P, int n) {
    double delta1 = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(FTCPPanel.WIDTH, 2) + Math.pow(FTCPPanel.HEIGHT, 2));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        bfList.add(P[i]);
        
        for (int j = i+1; j < n; j++) {
            double deltam = distance(P[i],P[j]);
            if(deltam < delta1) {
                delta1 = deltam;            
            }
        }
    }
    
    return delta1;
}
```

But it insert all the points of the beginning array P[n] inside it.
I don't understand if the brute force works for every 2 or 3 points and then insert all the points in the list or idk.
I just want to print my pair of closest points.

I modified my code in this way:

```
double delta1=Math.sqrt(Math.pow(FTCPPanel.WIDTH, 2)+Math.pow(FTCPPanel.HEIGHT, 2));
        for(int i=0; i<n;i++) {
            for(int j=i+1;j<n;j++) {
                double deltam=distance(P[i],P[j]);
                if(deltam<delta1) {
                    delta1=deltam;  
                    bfList.add(P[i]);
                    bfList.add(P[j]);
                }
            }
        }
        return delta1;
    }
```

and then I modified another class in this way:

```
public Point[] closestPointsArray(List<Point> list,List<Point> list1) {
        int size1 = list.size(); //another list with other points that I checked
        int size = list1.size(); //the bruteforce one
        double dist = Double.MAX_VALUE;
        System.out.println("list"+list); //this is just for my output
        Point[]cp=list.toArray(new Point[size1]);
        Point[] l= list1.toArray(new Point[size]);
        Point[]cp1 = new Point[2];
        
        System.out.println("list l"+list1);
        System.out.println("list cp"+list);
        
        for(int i=0;i<size; i=i+2) { //I use this one to can the array and found the closest here in the bruteforce, but something is wrong
                int j=i+1;
                double distij=distance(l[i],l[j]);
                if(distij<=dist) {
                    dist=distij;
                    cp1[0]=l[i];
                    cp1[1]=l[j];
                
            }
        }
        if(list.isEmpty()) {
            return cp1;
        }else {
            double distL=distance(cp1[0],cp1[1]);
            double distCP=distance(cp[0],cp[1]);
            System.out.println("dist L"+distL);
            System.out.println("dist CP"+distCP);
            
            if(distCP<distL) {
                return cp;
            }else {
                return cp1;
            }
        }
        
        
    }
```

I think that in this way I can scan my list in pair of (0,1),(2,3)....
but I don't know why sometimes the distance is 0.... when it isn't.

Comment: Your question is really how to find the points. You don't have a problem printing them, do you?

Comment: @aled I have this application that find the delta minimum, and it works, I have problem to how put the closest pair of point into an array to make them in a bright color in the panel. Cause the program always color the wrong points.

Answer (score 2):

Your solution is not correct, because in your outer loop you are adding the points to `bfList`:

```java
bfList.add(P[i]);
```

before even checking any condition. So, you have to move it to inner loop:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
        double deltam = distance(P[i], P[j]);
        if (deltam < delta1) {
            delta1 = deltam;
            bfList.clear(); // Clear the list and add the new closest points
            bfList.add(P[i]);
            bfList.add(P[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to add to the list just the one with the minimum distance, but I do the brute force more times, so it add in the list only the latest and this is not what I need.

Comment: can I create a new list every time and then compare them?

Comment: I edited my question with another part of code

Comment: @imtrying727 if I understood correctly, you just need to add some `ArrayList` before first for loop, and replace `bfList` with this `ArrayList` inside the inner loop. And before `return delta1` add them to `bfList`

Comment: I'll post my code that now works

Comment: Thank you btw cause I used this .clear() in another part of the code